How to make the regex negative lookbehind consume discarded text?
My regex is: /(?<!start )".*?"/ - it searches for quotes in text (actually for string literals in code)
For me, it works perfectly with these cases:

start "text" - doesn't match
123 "text" - match
"text" - match

But with cases like this it doesn't:

start "test " start " text" - it will match when I don't want it to (with " start ")

How can I make the regex negative lookbehind consume discarded text?

Can you reformat your question and clarify further what you don't want to match. Also what is your regex flavor?

(?<!start )"(?:(?!start)[^"\n])*" will work, too, if you do not expect start inside the quotes.

@WiktorStribiżew
I'm sorry I haven't provided sufficient examples, your example wouldn't work for me in this example:
start "test " s123tart " text".
Where it will match with the:
" s123tart "

Right, matching specific strings between identical characters is tricky.

You can use SKIP FAIL. There are other ways too, if you elaborate:
start\s+"[^"\r\n]*"(*SKIP)(*F)|"[^"\r\n]*"

Also see

Or:
\bstart\s+"[^"\r\n]*"(*SKIP)(*F)|"[^"\r\n]*"

See

Details

\bstart\s+"[^"\r\n]*"(*SKIP)(*F): matches first what you don't want, then it uses SKIP FAIL to remove it from results.

"[^"\r\n]*": All is left is what you want to match.



So nice!
If we rethink my simpler expression based on your example, it will be:
/start ".*?"(*SKIP)(*F)|".*?"/

@Rr Yes, that would work too.

apparently the VS 2024 doesn't support skip fail

@Rr You can remove the SKIP FAIL. (\bstart\s+"[^"\r\n]*")|("[^"\r\n]*") separates the two types. You can then program what you want to eventually achieve. If you edit your question according to the first comment under your question, they will help you out.

@Rr You can also uncheck the "Accept" box on the left to allow others to address your questions.

No, I like your answer. I will move on
